# What is the difference between a model of computation and a programming language?

Tags: computability, pl.programming-languages, concurrency, universal-computation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation includes sequential models, functional models and concurrency models.

- Sequential models include finite state machine, Turing machines, random access machine.
- Functional models include lambda calculus.
- Concurrency models include pi calculus, the actor model.

I have seen lambda calculus, pi calculus, and the actor model are formulated as languages with syntax and semantics.

1. Some books (such as Varela's *Programming Distributed Computing
   Systems*) present models of computations and then programming
   languages which "follow" the models.

   - What is the difference between a model of computation and a programming language, if both can be formulated as languages with
     syntax and semantics meaning computation? (For example, I didn't realize to make any distinction, and called lambda calculus as a programming language, but was corrected.)
   - What is the definition of the "follow" relationship between models of computation and programming languages?
2. I haven't found out whether finite state machine, Turing machines,
   and random access machine are formulated as languages with syntax
   and semantics. I wonder if they can be and why they aren't or are
   not often formulated as such?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no sharp difference!  A programming language is fully formal:
there is a compiler or interpreter that executes programs on a
machine. Models of computing are specified at the level of
"normal mathematics" which is somewhat informal. For
example: models of computing often use mathematical integers and
reals. Programming languages, use finite precision integers and
floats. Other idealisations include infinite vs finite memory, and
how to generate fresh names. So one could argue that models of
computing are slightly imprecise programming languages.

Comment: This informality let's you see core ideas more clearly, rather than drowning them out in edge cases like overflow/underflow and rounding modes of floats, at least when you are not interested in details of floats.

Comment: Sometimes a model of computing becomes so popular that people do formalise it, but then it is not always clear how exactly to do this, with the actor model being a good example.

Comment: Regarding $\lambda$-calculus, it might be worthwhile to see it as a
  family of calculi, one for each reduction strategy.
  $\lambda$-calculus, as originally conceived of for the purposes of
  formalising logic, reduces under $\lambda$ which you never do when
  using $\lambda$-inspired programming languages (well, almost never,
  there is partial evaluation ...) Strictly speaking you should also be clear what notion of program equivalence you assume ...

Comment: @MartinBerger Thanks. (1)  Is it correct that an algorithm models a computation, and an algorithm and a model of (a) computation are the same concept? (2) Does it make more sense to compare a **universal** model of computation and a programming language, than to compare a model of computation and a programming language?

Comment: (1) Programs are instances of algorithms, but we don't have a good abstract concept of algorithm, in the sense that the same algorithm can be implemented by distinct programs. For this reason algorithms and models of computation are very different. (2) As I said above: model of computation is a vague concept and usually used in a way that is similar to programming language, but less precise and focussing on a single feature.

Comment: @MartinBerger (2) Do you by any chance miss my point of distinguishing between model of computation and universal model of computation. (1)  An algorithm is defined as anything which a Turing machine can simulate. A model of computation is defined as a model of a computation. An algorithm and a model of computation are the same thing

Comment: it's fine to have a private language and define whatever you like. But if you want meaningful feedback from *others*, you will have to communicate in a language they understand, and, whether you like it or now, for your audience here,  algorithm and a model of computation are very much *not* the same thing.

Comment: @MartinBerger I don't have a "private" language, whatever you meant by that. My post is precisely asking about what I don't understand from publications of other people